# How can I see in iTunes how much time is left in audio books and podcasts?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

When listening to audio books and podcasts iTunes and iPods/iPhones remember the last position.

How can I see this piece of information in iTunes without playing the podcast? (It is displayed on my iPhone as "xx minutes left" in the list of podcasts.)

Answer (score 3):

In iTunes, when a podcast is playing, you can click the top bar where it says how long the podcast is. Clicking that will change the total time into the time remaining.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that's right. But how can I do it without playing the podcast? (I'll edit the question accordingly.)